# How do I insert a cell value into a text string that contains text strings? (Excel/Google Spreadsheets)

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Let's say I want to create the following text in C1:

**{"types":["A1","B1"}**

So far I've been able to get: **{"types":["Grass**

with this formula: **="{""types"": ["""&A1**

I'm currently getting formula parse errors when adding a quotation after A1.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
="{""types"": ["""&A1&""","""&B1&"""]}"
```